# git pull --rebase

Tags: git, git-rebase

Start situation (no unpushed changes, `>` indicates the current branch):

```
o C [> master][origin/master]
|
o B
|
o A
|
...
```

After a `git fetch` the log structure often looks like

```
o E [origin/master]
|
o C'
|
o B'
|
o D
|
| o C [>master]
| |
| o B
|/
o A
|
...
```

Now `git rebase origin/master master` often produces conflicts. Is `git pull --rebase` smarter and just uses `git reset` to make `master` also point to `E` if `master`==`origin/master` initially?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`git pull --rebase` is similar to what the following would do:

```
git fetch
git rebase
```

So in your case it will leave the repository like this:

```
o C [> master]
|
o B
|
o E [origin/master]
|
o C'
|
o B'
|
o D
|
o A
|
...
```

Note that the two commits you have are different from `origin` where re-created on top of commit E.

Comment: It looks like you've mixed `B` with `B'` and `C` with `C'`. Unfortunately, in practice this does not work well if `B` and `C` are already part of `origin/master` (as a result of a previous cherry-pick or rebase).

Comment: `git pull --rebase` is *not* the same as `git fetch; git rebase` - see [my answer below which gives the difference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11531552/179332).

Comment: The last sentence is incomprehensible.

Answer (score 18):

You can pull with rebase instead of merge - that's the way my team works and it works quite well.

From "[A few git tips you didn't know about](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/07/git-tips/)":

> Because branch merges in git are recorded with a merge commit, they
>   are supposed to be meaningful—for example, to indicate when a feature
>   has been merged to a release branch. However, during a regular daily
>   workflow where several team members sync a single branch often, the
>   timeline gets polluted with unnecessary micro-merges on regular git
>   pull. Rebasing ensures that the commits are always re-applied so that
>   the history stays linear.
>
> You can configure certain branches to always do this without the
>   --rebase flag:
>
> `#make 'git pull' on master always use rebase` 
>   `$ git config branch.master.rebase true`
>
> You can also set up a global option to set
>   the last property for every new tracked branch:
>
> `# setup rebase for every tracking branch`
>   `$ git config --global branch.autosetuprebase always`

Answer (score 17):

`git pull --rebase` is **NOT** the same as `git fetch; git rebase`.  Unfortunately the `git-pull` man page is rather cryptic about the difference:

```
   --rebase
       Rebase the current branch on top of the upstream branch
       after fetching. If there is a remote-tracking branch
       corresponding to the upstream branch and the upstream branch
       was rebased since last fetched, the rebase uses that
       information to avoid rebasing non-local changes.
```

It turns out that the difference doesn't involve `git reset` as the original poster guessed - in fact it involves the *reflog* (see [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#RefLog-Shortnames) if you haven't encountered that term before).

For the complete story around the extra magic in `git pull --rebase`, see this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11531502/179332