# What's the difference between `git fetch` then `git rebase`, and `git pull --rebase`?

Tags: git, git-rebase

In reading the `git pull` page, it gives this stern warning about `git pull --rebase`:

> This is a potentially dangerous mode of operation. It rewrites history, which does not bode well when you published that history already. Do not use this option unless you have read git-rebase(1) carefully.

In the `git rebase` page, it gives a lot of description but no warning of this sort.

In addition, I've seen some people say that

```
git fetch
git rebase
```

is the same as

```
git pull --rebase
```

while others say they're *slightly* different.

What's the truth?

Comment: Really good book about git that you should keep under your pillow http://progit.org/

Comment: The warning on the `git pull` page makes it sound like things can go awry quite easily.  But the description in the book makes it sound like you have to make an effort to screw up rebasing.

Comment: What I've ended up doing regularly is using `git fetch` to update my view of the remote repo, and then looking at the pulled-down history and deciding what I want to do.  (Usually I follow it up with a `git rebase`.)

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930527/difference-between-git-pull-and-git-pull-rebase

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The rule with Git is that you should never attempt to change history after it has been shared, published, or pushed. You can do so, of course, if you really want to and have sufficient permissions, but it should be done with great care since it can mess other people up.

Now fortunately when you have a typical Git deployment with a single upstream repository (origin) which is the source of all that is good and true in the universe, you can use `git pull --rebase` to your heart's content and it will be perfectly safe and in my opinion give you a much more sane (meaning linear) history. I and my team use it continuously.

However, if you start having multiple remotes and start doing `git pull --rebase <arguments>` so that you are no longer rebasing against the same target every time, or start pushing your branch to alternate repositories *before* running `git pull --rebase` with your primary upstream—then you can start running into troubles.

Any time where you share your changes with another remote/repository and then change those changes (for values of changing equal to changing the SHA, parent, etc. even if the commit message/content did not change), you can mess up the person who had the old changes.

As long as you don't fall outside the envelope of rebase sanity, `git pull --rebase` will be very good for you.

That, err, doesn't answer the question about the difference between `git pull --rebase` and `git fetch && git rebase @{u}`. I'll just go ahead and say that I am unaware of any difference and if there is one, it is subtle enough that I have not noticed it in the years I have used Git. Possibly in that the system figures out the correct repository your branch should fetch if you have multiple repositories and "origin" isn't the upstream of this branch?

And even if you do go very awry with git-rebase, you can of course recover yourself back to your original pre-rebase environment easily with `git log -g` and/or `git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD`. Just don't do force pushes (disallowed by default in almost all Git servers), and you will be happy happy.

### EDITED

With time my understanding has expanded. `git pull --rebase` calls `git rebase` to do the rebase work, so in that sense there is no difference between them. However, git-pull actually calls `git rebase --onto @{u} $(git merge-base HEAD @{u}@{1})`

OK, that syntax ("@{u}@{1}") is perhaps a little opaque and is a simplification to boot, but the point is that it finds out what the merge base was to upstream *BEFORE* it ran the fetch command. What difference does this make, you ask?

Well, in the normal case none. However, if you are changing where upstream is pointing to or if upstream itself was rebased, quite a lot. If upstream was rewritten and then you did a `git rebase @{u}` you could be very unhappy and could get double-commits or conflicts depending on how much the older commits were rewritten.

However, with the magic behind `git pull --rebase` only the commits which are yours and yours alone will be applied on top of @{u}.

OK, this *too* is a simplification. If upstream did a rebase starting with the 100 commits ago (but there are actually 101+ commits in history) *and* you did a `git fetch` *before* doing a `git pull --rebase` then Git will not be able to accurately determine what the proper historical merge-base was to figure out what your local commits are.

The upshot of which is, `git fetch` is considered harmful (when you have local commits and upstream is rewritten).  However, the real rule-of-thumb is "never attempt to change history after it has been shared, published, or pushed" which is where I started.

## TL;DR:

`git fetch` is considered harmful (so use `git pull --rebase`); and never attempt to change history after it has been shared, published, or pushed (because, among other things, it will cause `git fetch` to be harmful).

Comment: TL;DR (perhaps the answer to the questions are buried in there but I'll never know:)

Comment: @RickO'Shea: Added a TL;DR just for *you*.

Comment: TLDR is wrong: `git fetch` cannot be possibly harmful! It does not do anything but to get new objects from remote. It does not change state of local checkout or local branches in any way.

Comment: @mvp: You are correct that fetch does not change the local branches, but that doesn't stop it from being harmful (under the specific circumstances I outlined in the paragraph above the TL;DR).  If you think I am ''now'' wrong about those circumstances (I have not checked this part of git recently) please dispute the technical details, not the broad summary.

Comment: @SethRobertson perhaps what @mvp meant is that your TL;DR should be a summary of your answer to the full question "What's the difference between `git fetch` then `git rebase`, and `git pull --rebase`?" and not only a summary of your last paragraph, because as it stands right now, anyone glancing over your answer looking for a TL;DR will read "`git fetch` is considered harmful? I thought `git fetch` just fetches and doesn't change anything? And how does that answer the question of `git pull --rebase` / `git rebase`?"

Comment: @AlaaAli: yes, that's exactly what I meant: `git fetch` cannot possibly be harmful by itself. As it stands, this answer does not make any sense, at least to me.

Comment: @mvp: You are right, `git fetch` is not harmful *by itself*.  It is harmful because it causes git to lose information that allows subsequent commands like `git pull --rebase` or `git rebase` to work in the best possible way if someone else rewrote history.  You can normally get away with it because all three circumstances rarely happen at the same time.

Comment: @AlaaAli: Expanded the TL;DR for you to include a hint as to why the `git fetch` is harmful as explained in the full answer.

Comment: @SethRobertson: unfortunately, I still don't buy it.

Answer (score 46):

The truth is that they **ARE** different. Here's a really helpful web page which explains it beautifully:

http://gitolite.com/git-pull--rebase.html

So **`git pull --rebase` has some significant magic over `git fetch; git rebase`** which most of the time you won't notice, but in cases where the upstream maintainer has naughtily ignored all those stern warnings and decided to rewrite the history of a public branch, it can really help out by consulting your local reflog and doing the local rebase in a more intelligent way.

That said, this is still a rebase, so you are still rewriting history! Therefore all the standard stern warnings still apply.  But if you're working on a private (i.e. unpublished) branch, then that's OK.

I'll say a bit more regarding the stern warnings. They are valid, but personally I find most people just a bit *too* paranoid about rebase, like a `git rebase` crept into their bedroom in the middle of the night when they were young and ate their sister or something. It really shouldn't be that scary:

- if it's a private branch, rebase to your heart's content
- if it's a public branch don't rebase unless you *really* have to, and if you do, make sure you understand the impact, and make sure anyone who might be impacted is properly informed about what you've done, so they don't get a nasty surprise and waste a load of time figuring out what happened.

It's that simple. And yes, I would go as far as actively encouraging people to regularly `git rebase -i` on their private branches. Polishing history before pushing to somewhere public/upstream is [a good thing](http://blog.adamspiers.org/2012/11/10/7-principles-for-contributing-patches-to-software-projects/#cleanliness), because no one wants to wade through a project's history which is full of commits like 'oops, fixing a mistake I made 3 commits ago'. (OTOH, don't get totally obsessed with rebasing in quest of a flawless history.  We're human. We make mistakes. Deal with it.)

One last observation regarding the `git pull --rebase` magic.  If the upstream public branch has been rebased in a sensible way (e.g. squashing / fixing up commits, or dropping commits which shouldn't have been put there) then the magic works in your favour. However if the upstream rebase accidentally *dropped* commits, then the magic will silently prevent you from putting them  back. In this case if you want to put back those dropped commits, you should instead use `git fetch; git rebase`.

Answer (score -6):

In addition to updating your local branch from its remote tracking branch, the `-pull` updates your workspace files.

So it's probably more typical to `git pull --rebase` (or configure pull to use rebase by default) than to `git fetch; git rebase`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. Additionally it appears that you downvoted my correct answer despite not having the patience to read it.