# Working on the same branch, how to pull without losing changes?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-pull

I am working on the same branch as my colleagues. Now I have committed some files and sent for code review and so has some other co-worker. Now he pushes his code before I do. I now need to pull his changes back and then add my changes. But it's already committed.

How do I get his changes and then add my changes without the history looking bad and me having to jump hoops? I am very new to git.

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930527/difference-between-git-pull-and-git-pull-rebase

Comment: Please provide any explanation about the exact flow you've made. The answer realy realy depends on it.  
"*Now I have committed some files and sent for code review*" => Do you mean you pushed ? If yes, what branch ?  
"*Now he pushes his code before I do*" => what branch ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `git pull --rebase`. This will fetch your collegues commits and then put your commits (that you haven't pushed) on top of them, keeping the history looking good as well.

Edit:  Cyril CHAPON made some good points in his comment. Take a look at some of his links to fully understand the how rebase works and to avoid pitfalls.

Comment: Any advise including a `rebase` should include a warning about the [golden rule](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing/the-golden-rule-of-rebasing/). Plus, even if that answer is that closest one, it dramatically deserves some explanations, at least a [useful link](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing)

Answer (score 2):

As already stated you can do a `git pull --rebase` but there is also a different approach you go with:
Imagine your history now look like this:

`A -> B -> C -> D
           |    | local master
           remote/master`

You can do the following:

`$ git branch save_state
 $ git reset --hard C`

Basically this brings you to

`A -> B -> C (remote/master)
           \ -> D (local save_state)`

You know pull the changes from remote into your master

`$ git pull origin master`

Which will lead to a fast forward merge(history is clean up to here)
And know you can do a

`$ git checkout save_state
 $ git rebase master
 $ git checkout master && git merge save_state`
You can rebase this branch here without problems because it doesnt have been pushed to remote yet.

Comment: Exactly same remark as [my previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30390337/working-on-the-same-branch-how-to-pull-without-losing-changes/30390416#comment48871182_30390416). He stated that he **already pushed** for code review, including any possible other commits by his community **after** his work. Rebasing should be realy realy warned.

Comment: He just stated he commited and send for review. Does'nt implicitly mean he already pushed I would guess.

Comment: You're right. "*Sent*" isn't obvious and the following explanation about "*Now he pushes his code before I do*" should include any branch name or whatever.

Comment: Yup, we should wait for any reaction of the QO,and if he really pushed already, I will definitly edit my answer. Because you are absolutly right then. Rebasing after pushin isn't a good idea though :D

Answer (score 0):

```
git pull
```

That will get his changes from the remote server, bring them locally to your machine, and then merge his work in with yours.  This will give a join in the history: one branch with your work, one with his, and then a join when the two are brought together.  Git will give you the opportunity to fix any conflicts if that is necessary, but it does a great job of merging automatically.

I very strongly recommend that you read this: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2