# Avoiding merge commits in pull requests in git

Tags: git, github

So, I want to create a pull request that only includes the changes to file1, file2, and file3 (i.e. updates for a feature).

The workflow I used:

```
git clone https://github.com/eghm/project.git project-eghm-clean
cd project-eghm-clean
git remote add upstream https://github.com/forkeduser/project.git
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/master
git push
git branch featurebranch
git checkout featurebranch
#edit files: file1, file2, file3
git add file1
git add file2
git add file3
git commit -m 'updates for feature'
git push --set-upstream origin featurebranch
```

Then on github I went to my forked repository, selected Branch: featurebranch, and clicked Pull request.  The request includes my merges from synching my fork:

[image: pull request includes sync merges]

How can I avoid this in the future?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should just `git rebase` against the branch that you're issuing your pull request against.  For instance:

```
git rebase origin/master
```

Since this will change the history of your branch, you are better off doing this rebase in a new branch.  So:

```
git checkout -b new_rebased_branch
git rebase origin/master
```

For future reference, if you don't want merge commits in your pull requests, you should try to update your branches via rebase rather than merge.  Again, I always recommend checking out a separate branch to do this in, since rebasing will change your commit history, you may want to keep a backup of the original commit history.

Answer (score 2):

Since  [Dec. 4th 2019](https://github.blog/changelog/2019-12-04-expanded-branch-protection-rules/), you could try and protect your PR branch and reject any push that contains a merge commit by enabling `Require linear history`.

That would ensure you are force to use `git pull --rebase`, because otherwise, you would not be able to push.

Answer (score 1):

As @mkrufky points out, you should use `git rebase` to rebase your work onto the master branch. However, it is not necessary to create a new branch, as rebase does not really rewrite the history, but rather "replays" the commits onto the new base. Git even keeps track of all the old commits in the `git reflog` for a certain time, which prevents you from losing your history that way.

The correct workflow would be:

```
git fetch origin master
git rebase origin/master
```

But, that's exactly what `git pull --rebase` does! It is an option to rebase your work onto the branch you're pulling against instead of doing a merge of the two branches.

You can find more explanations here: [Difference between git pull and git pull --rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930527/difference-between-git-pull-and-git-pull-rebase) and in the Rebasing chapter of the git manual: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing