# What is the rebase command used in hg pull --rebase

Tags: mercurial, rebase

Typically, in HG my workflow is to exclusively use:

```
hg pull --rebase
```

If I wanted to run this in two commands, how would I do it?

```
hg pull
hg rebase <probably with some options?>
```

Comment: I suspect it's similar to git: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930527/difference-between-git-pull-and-git-pull-rebase

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What `hg pull --rebase` does is to indeed first do a `hg pull` and then `hg rebase` with default arguments on top of that (you can look at the code in `rebase.py` in the Mercurial distribution in function `pullrebase()`), but *only if any new revisions were pulled in*. If no rebasing is necessary, `hg pull --rebase` will update to the new branch tip instead. So, `hg pull && hg rebase` is approximately correct, but doesn't quite capture some corner cases (no new revisions, no rebase necessary).

By default, `hg rebase` will use the parent of the working directory as the *base revision* of the rebase and the most recent revision of the current branch (i.e. usually what you just pulled in) as the destination. In short, it's equivalent to `hg rebase -b . -d 'last(branch(.))'`.

What does "base revision" mean in this context? It means that Mercurial will go and look for the least common ancestor of the base revision and the destination. Then it will rebase everything up to, but not including that least common ancestor on top of the destination. I.e., specifying the base revision allows you to pick pretty much any revision on the branch [1] that you want to rebase and let Mercurial figure out which revisions belong to that branch.

Note that because the rebase is based on the parent of the current working directory, this means that if your current checkout is *not* what you have been working on, then `hg pull --rebase` may surprise you by actually trying to rebase a different branch (it will usually fail, because those revisions are generally part of the public phase, but it's something you need to be aware of if you're working with so-called [non-publishing repositories](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Phases#Publishing_Repository) *and* don't use named branches).

[1] Branch in this context refers to an anonymous or topological branch, not a named branch. See `hg help glossary` for further details.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rebase by hand (**bad idea** in common), you have to

- Read `hg help rebase` before
- Understand usable for you options of rebase (at least `-s` and `-d`)
- Use these options

Let's see at toy-repos:

Repo A

```
A>hg log -T "{rev} {desc}\n"
1 A2
0 A1
```

with 2 changesets  A1 and A2 was cloned to repos `B` and `C` (B for `pull --rebase A`, C for clean `pull A`)

and two additional changesets was added to A and B+C after clone in order to test your use-case (diverged history)

```
A>hg log -T "{rev} {desc}\n"
3 A2++
2 A2+
1 A2
0 A1

B>hg log -T "{rev} {desc}\n"
3 B2
2 B1
1 A2
0 A1
```

C state is identical to B

```
B>hg pull --rebase 
...
B>hg log -T "{rev} {desc}\n" -G
@  5 B2
|
o  4 B1
|
o  3 A2++
|
o  2 A2+
|
o  1 A2
|
o  0 A1
```

I.e. result of rebased pull is "linear history with local changes on top of remote changes", compared to just pull from C

```
C>hg log -T "{rev} {desc}\n" -G
@  5 A2++
|
o  4 A2+
|
| o  3 B2
| |
| o  2 B1
|/
o  1 A2
|
o  0 A1
```

or, in GUI

[image: B-repo] [image: C-repo]

and in order to get B from C, you have to rebase 2 (`-s 2`) to new parent 5 (`-d 5`), but short `hg rebase -b 2` will work also and will have the same effect

Comment: `If you want to rebase by hand (bad idea in common)`
Why is this a bad idea?

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude - because Mercurial-way is (more) merge diverged history, contrary to Git-style of avoiding merges

Comment: Does that mean I should avoid `hg pull --rebase` as well?

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude - it's more personal tastes, than must-have workflow... I prefer do **all** operations by hand (`--rebase` can be unpredictable) and merges instead rebase: I can see later TRUE history