# Git Rebase Leads to Duplicate Code Review?

Tags: git, github

Let's say I branch off of `development` with a feature branch:

```
development: A--B
                 \
feature:          C
```

Meanwhile, another branch is merged into `development`, adding the commit `D`:

```
development: A--B--D
                 \
feature:          C
```

So on branch `feature`, I `git rebase development`:

```
development: A--B--D
                    \
feature:             C
```

But now when I create a pull request to merge `feature` back into development, commit `D` appears as if it were a new change. I understand in reality there are two `D` commits, the original and a copy on the feature branch. But now I'm reviewing changes (`D`) that I already reviewed in a previous PR into `development`. Am I using `rebase` correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand in reality there are two D commits, the original and a copy on the feature branch.

Only if you've made a mistake during the rebase. If `develop` pointed at commit D when you ran the rebase, then the rebase command would only have recreated commit C on top of it.

The most likely explanation I can think of is that you've run git rebase *twice*, once rebasing C correctly onto D, and then again rebasing both C and D onto B.

A common mistake is to rebase onto your local branch `develop` without updating it from the remote branch first. Instead of `git rebase develop`, you probably want to run `git pull --rebase origin develop` , or `git fetch origin; git rebase origin/develop` so that you're bringing in all the changes from the remote branch.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing a `git rebase` you might want to use `git pull --rebase`.

This will perform a `fetch` and pull the changes from the remote, so you can fix conflicts (if any).

You can refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017517/git-pull-rebase-vs-git-rebase-whats-the-danger) so you can see more details about it.

Answer (score 0):

You never gave the specifics of where/how you are "reviewing" changes, but I will point out here that in your post-rebase branch, the `C` commit is actually a *new* commit:

```
development: A -- B -- D
                        \
feature:                 C'     (the ' indiciates this is a NEW commit)
```

As a result, the changes introduced by the `D` commit in the `development` branch could appear differently as they interact with your work from the `C'` commit.