# What is the process to update .git files after renaming repo?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I rename repos on BitBucket and and get error when I try to push again. I renamed one repo and now see:

```
cchilders:~/projects/gitflow_automation (master) 
$ showorigin 
repository does not exist.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

So I do

```
$ rm -rf .git
$ git init
$ git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:codyc54321/gitflow_automation.git
```

This adds the newly named repo (the same repo though, just new name) to the new `.git` files.

I then did

```
cchilders:~/projects/gitflow_automation 
$ showorigin 
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git@bitbucket.org:codyc54321/gitflow_automation.git
  Push  URL: git@bitbucket.org:codyc54321/gitflow_automation.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)

cchilders:~/projects/gitflow_automation 
$ git pull
remote: Counting objects: 70, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (55/55), done.
remote: Total 70 (delta 20), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (70/70), done.
From bitbucket.org:codyc54321/gitflow_automation
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master


cchilders:~/projects/gitflow_automation 
$ nano FAKE

cchilders:~/projects/gitflow_automation 
$ cmpushall "test new repo name working"
[master (root-commit) 7b0a190] test new repo name working
 21 files changed, 601 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitignore
 create mode 100644 FAKE
 create mode 100644 README.md
 create mode 100644 __init__.py
 create mode 100644 gitflow/__init__.py
 create mode 100644 gitflow/client.py
 create mode 100644 gitflow/config/__init__.py
 create mode 100644 gitflow/github_webdriver_client/__init__.py
 create mode 100644 gitflow/pivotal_tracker_webdriver_client/__init__.py
 create mode 100644 gitflow/user.py
 create mode 100644 gitflow/webdriver_base/__init__.py
 create mode 100644 requirements.txt
 create mode 100755 scripts/make_stories.py
 create mode 100755 scripts/open_pull_request.py
 create mode 100755 scripts/open_pull_request.sh
 create mode 100644 tests/__init__.py
 create mode 100644 tests/test_github_user_login_info.py
 create mode 100644 tests/test_github_webdriver_client/__init__.py
 create mode 100644 tests/test_github_webdriver_client/test_github_driver.py
 create mode 100644 tests/test_pivotal_tracker_webdriver_client/__init__.py
 create mode 100644 tests/test_pivotal_tracker_webdriver_client/test_pivotal_tracker_driver.py
To bitbucket.org:codyc54321/gitflow_automation.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@bitbucket.org:codyc54321/gitflow_automation.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

cchilders:~/projects/gitflow_automation (master) 
$ git fetch 

cchilders:~/projects/gitflow_automation (master) 
$ git pull

There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master
```

Causing this problem:

```
cchilders:~/projects/gitflow_automation (master) 
$ git pull origin  master 
From bitbucket.org:codyc54321/gitflow_automation
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

Is there a way to rename a repo on BitBucket or GitHub?

Comment: but on `git pull origin master ` I get `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`

Comment: why did you `rm -f .git`?!

Comment: Probably because you already commited. Start from scratch and pull __before__ you do _any_ commit.

Comment: I removed `.git` because after renaming it in bitbucket I get `repository does not exist.`

Comment: idk what "start from scratch and pull" means without seeing it. should I always delete entire repo and `git clone {repo}` to retrieve the git history when I rename one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if its going to work but i guess you can try these,

Try `git pull --rebase`

see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930527/difference-between-git-pull-and-git-pull-rebase)

You can use `--allow-unrelated-histories` to force the merge to happen like this

```
git pull origin branchname --allow-unrelated-histories
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, the `git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories` worked like a charm. ty

Comment: great! my pleasure. If the answer was helpful then i ask you for kindly accept it as well. thank you too.

Answer (score 12):

**To update the remote url in your local repository run (for ssh):**

```
git remote set-url origin git@git***.com:owner/project_name.git
```

**or for http(s):**

```
git remote set-url origin https://git***.com/nh-ad/dynamic-audiance-segment.git
```

Answer (score 0):

Danish's `git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories` worked:

[image]

showing some weird detached part rejoined, where I had renamed it and deleted .git