# git pull --rebase explanation

Tags: git, rebase, git-pull

Starting point: I have created a branch from `master` and locally made commits. Other commits have, during my branch work, been PR'd into `master`...

What I would then do, locally, is `git checkout master`, `git pull`, then checkout my branch and `git rebase master`

My understanding is that - at this point - all the commits I've made while working on my branch will be applied "after" those `master` commits.

My understand of `git pull --rebase` is that it does as I've described above. My question is (assuming that is correct) how does the `git pull --rebase` know **which branch I am rebasing on?**

In the steps above I have rebased onto the `HEAD` of `master`, whereas most `git pull --rebase` explanations appear to focus on rebasing upon commits made to the **same** branch (not the original `master`).

My typical steps, explicitly:

```
git clone <path>
cd <dir>
git checkout -b feature/my-branch
<make changes>
git add .
git commit -m "some message"
git checkout master
git pull --all
git checkout feature/my-branch
git rebase master
**git push --set-upstream origin feature/my-branch**
```

Question: Can/Should I change the above steps to:

```
git clone <path>
cd <dir>
git checkout -b feature/my-branch
**git push --set-upstream origin feature/my-branch**
<make changes>
git add .
git commit -m "some message"
git pull -r
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between git pull and git pull --rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930527/difference-between-git-pull-and-git-pull-rebase)

Comment: do `git branch -vv` to see the tracked upstream branch for each branch you have locally

Comment: Note that `git pull --all` simply passes `--all` to `git fetch`. This is a useless option; don't use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your current procedure, you leave `master` at `origin/master` (because you're working on a branch).  Then when you pull, the resulting merge is a fast-forward, and you can then `rebase` your branch onto `master` to keep a linear history (if you're into that sort of thing).

You could do a `--rebase` pull, and it would work exactly the same, because you're not in the situation where `--rebase` is meaningful.  When pulling `master`, `--rebase` changes what the pull does with commits *in `master` but not in `origin/master`* - and in your scenario there are none.

What `--rebase` lets you do is not create the branch in the first place but still end with a linear history (if you're into that sort of thing).  Let's say instead of

```
A -- B -- C <--(master)(origin/master)
           \
            D -- E -- F <--(branch)
```

you instead had

```
A -- B -- C <--(origin/master)
           \
            D -- E -- F <--(master)
```

because you did your work directly on master.  Now if you did a "normal" `pull` you would get

```
A -- B -- C ---- X ---- Y <--(origin/master)
           \             \
            D -- E -- F -- M <--(master)
```

But if you use `git pull --rebase` then the pull will rebase the local `master` onto the newly-fetched `origin/master` instead, so you get

```
A -- B -- C -- X -- Y <--(origin/master)
                     \
                      D -- E -- F <--(master)
```

which is the same linear history you'd get by doing `D..F` on a branch and rebasing that yourself after `pull`ing `X..Y` into `master`.

Comment: What you're saying is that if I'm working on a branch which tracks it's remote version, there is no use for 'git pull -r'. I'm looking to understand if I can use 'git pull -r' to rebase my branch to the HEAD of master, without tracking master. The answer appears to be No. What you've described above would appear to require commit permissions on master, which I do not have, hence the requirement to create a branch.

Comment: @MattW : (1) No, I did not say that there's no use for `-r` when your branch tracks its remote version.  In fact I showed exactly what that use is.  (2) What you're describing (pulling a branch other than the upstream and rebasing onto it) is in fact possible, contrary to the answer you accepted; it just wasn't clear that's what you were asking.  To do this, `git pull -r origin master`

Answer (score 1):

A branch can be set to track an upstream branch.

```
git branch --set-upstream my_branch origin/master
```

This is not needed if you do this when creating the branch:

```
git checkout -b my_branch origin/master
```

When the upstream branch is set you can check out `my_branch` and do `git pull -r`. For both the above cases it will be rebased on `origin/master`.

You can list branches together with their tracked upstream branches doing this:

```
git branch -vv
```

If you want `feature/my-branch` to track `origin/feature/my-branch` i would suggest to change this in your typical steps:

```
git checkout -b feature/my-branch
```

to:

```
git checkout -b feature/my-branch origin/feature/my-branch
```

Notice that `git checkout -b feature/my-branch` is equal to `git checkout -b feature/my-branch HEAD`. In other words, the branch is created to point to the commit you have checked out and with no upstream branch set.

Comment: Thanks. Possibly I'm not clear on 'tracking the upstream'. If I do 'git branch -vv' I get a list of branches which all track a remote branch of the same name. My understanding is that if I set my local branches to track the branch I was on when I created the branch, I would be inadvertantly pushing commits to that source branch. I've updated my question.

Comment: In fact, the answer to the question "When should I use git pull --rebase?" would seem to answer this: "when your changes do not require a separate branch." https://stackoverflow.com/a/2472606/71376 Mine do. Oh well.