# What branch GIT considers as source branch while creating new branch?

Tags: git, github, version-control, version

I am new to GIT & in learning phase of GIT Concepts. I have two simple & quick questions.

Q1. Whenever we want to create a new branch, we type below command:

```
git checkout -b BranchName
```

Here, my question is that `git checkout` consider which branch as it's source branch while creating new branch?

- Does it consider `master` branch as source branch?
- Does it consider current branch as source branch?

Q2. Suppose, whatever branch which it is considering as source branch is not up to date from remote. So while creating a new branch from that source branch, does it create a pull for the source branch & then create new one OR it considers local branch as it's base and doesn't pull anything from server?

Comment: You will create a branch from your current branch and if it is not up to date your new branch won't have any new commits as well. So first `git pull` on your current branch - then create a new one and.

Comment: Ok..so it means source branch will be my current branch & best practice is to first pull your current branch & then create new one. But I did not get your point "if it is not up to date your new branch won't have any new commits as well". Could you please explain it?

Comment: Let's say you have branch A with commits #1, #2, #3 (imaginary hashes). It's your local branch. Your team member adds new stuff and pushes to the remote. This will be commit #4. You don't have it in your local branch until `git pull`. So if you create a new branch `B` and don't do `git pull` on A first, you won't have the latest changes (#4) in `B`, because your local A will be used as a source and it is not up-to-date with the remote. Does it make any sense ?)

Comment: What do you think "source branch" means?  It doesn't mean anything in Git.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT - none of the answer helped me here..it is the comment by john..which helped me here.

Answer (score 2):

There is no notion of source branch. The branch is what we call a 'ref', a pointer toward a commit.

So when you create a branch, the branch point toward the commit you are on (or indirectly, the first commit pointed by the current branch you are on).

If you don't specify a specific commit via a has or a refspec, git will create the branch on the commit with the following hash that you could get with the command:

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

Answer (score 1):

It will consider as source your current branch or use one more arg:

```
git checkout -b BranchName StartPoint
```

Note: below I answer to Q2:

If the start point is not up to date and you did not commit anything locally, you can pull, otherwise you could rebase it (alternatively you can merge, still using the pull).
`git fetch --all` refreshes history from the remote
You may be a few commits behind. Then `git rebase origin/master` (or whatever the branch) thus updating it and putting your commits on top.

Comment: Fetch != pull != rebase.

Comment: First you must fetch. in order to retrieve the history from the remote. Then you must rebase, in order to update by adding commits you eventually missed from remote and add yours on top. Lastly you can rebase.

Comment: You can also pull without rebase: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18930527.

Comment: Thanks for answering my first question. For second, I think the best practice is to first pull the branch to keep it up to date & then create new one.

Comment: Well you pull when you didn't really commit anything yourself locally.

Comment: No, you can merge instead of rebase. See the difference here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16666089/3429133.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I mainly use rebase so yes, it's worth mentioning. I will probably delete this answer then

Comment: I do prefer rebasing, too. But „must rebase“ is misleading and may confuses people.