# Git fetching updated code from bitbucket to digital ocean

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I am confused as I am doing it first time.

So I have total three copies of my project.

1. In my local laptop
2. In bitbucket
3. Live server (Digital Ocean)

Now, I did some update in configuration in `Live server copy` and didn't do the same in `Local copy`.

I have re-written some of my code in local machine and then git push my code to bitbucket.

Now I want to pull all the changes to the `LIVE SERVER COPY` from the bitbucket's updated code.

How can I do that? 
I did `git fetch origin master` and it gives me a message like this 
`* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD`

**EDIT**
After doing `git pull` I see this error

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
.env
config/nuxt.js
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
```

Aborting

and I know the above two files code are different from local/bitbucket copy and I actually don't want to over ride the above files but want other changes to get pulled from bitbucket to live server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: try `git pull --rebase`  provided your origin is saved

Comment: Or just `git pull`

Comment: What is the desired final outcome? Do you have changes on bitbucket that are not in your local copy? Do you want the configuration changes from your live server in your local copy? Generally you should add configuration to version control since this will vary between development and production environments.

Comment: Thank you @all. I have updated the question. Please see.

Comment: @prudviraj I get this error `Cannot pull with rebase: You have unstaged changes.` and may be because I changed some code in live and didn't push to bitbucket.

Comment: I was able to solve using this `git reset --hard
git pull
 `

Comment: @sadek  check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930527/difference-between-git-pull-and-git-pull-rebase