# When should I use git pull --rebase instead of git pull?

Tags: git

I have a local commit [A] and a branch which points at commit [B]. I need to pull changes before pushing the commit.

**Scenario 1:**

> Changes of commit [A] do not affect anything changed on commit [B]

`git pull` should be fine, pull should not overwrite anything. Same for using `git pull --rebase`.

**Scenario 2:**

> Changes of commit [A] and commit [B] affect the same file

`git pull` should be fine, git should automerge everything. Same for using `git pull --rebase`.

**Scenario 3:**

> Changes (or deletions) of commit [A] and commit [B] affect the lines of code.

`git pull` results into merge conflicts which I need to remove manually. Same for using `git pull --rebase`.

Am I wrong? In which cases I need to use `git pull --rebase` ? If you pull changes you need to rebase the commit anyway, either by `auto merge`, `no merge` or solving `merge conflicts`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472254/when-should-i-use-git-pull-rebase

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930527/difference-between-git-pull-and-git-pull-rebase

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+difference+between+%22git+pull%22+%22git+pull+--rebase%22

Comment: I almost got it, could you post at least one more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `git pull --rebase` in all three cases.  However, in the scenarios 2 and 3, you will have a new merge commit.  The message will say that you are merging `Branch 'foo' into branch 'foo'` and with branches that have a lot of changes can make the history really confusing.  Using `git pull --rebase` will not have these merge commits and will show a fairly straight forward history in the git log.