# git pull --rebase silently omits the rebase conflicts

Tags: git

**Someone marked this as duplicates, but it does not tell why `git rebase` as no conflicts while `git pull` has**

I have two clones of the same repo, `C1` and `C2` and their HEADs are both at commit `M1` which has some changes to file `F`.

Assume no `.gitconfig` file and `.git/config` for the file is the default generated by `git`

#### In `C1`

1. I modify `F` (at the same place that `M1` modified `F`)
2. `git commit -a --amend --no-edit` to rewrite `M1`, which results in a new commit `M2`.
3. `git push -f` to overwrite the remote.

#### In `C2`

- I do `git fetch`. So the `origin/master == M2` while `HEAD == M1`

since `M1` and `M2` both modified `F`, any of the following commands will enter `merge conflict` state:

- `git merge origin/master`
- `git merge`
- `git rebase origin/master`
- `git pull`

**However, the following commands does not trigger `merge conflicts` and set `HEAD` to `M2`**

- `git rebase`
- `git pull --rebase`

#### Questions

- Is this behavior correct by design?
- What is the difference between `git rebase` and `git rebase origin/master`
- What does `git pull --rebase` do?

Previously, I always thought

- `git pull` is the same as `git fetch && git merge origin/master`
- `git pull --rebase` is the same as `git fetch && git rebase origin/master`

But this experiment invalidates my thought.

---

The situation does not change even if I commit another `M3` on top of `M2` and push in `C1`. In `C2` it will still reset to `M3` and the `M1` is lost.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between git pull and git pull --rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930527/difference-between-git-pull-and-git-pull-rebase)

Comment: No, please do not mark it as duplicate.

Comment: That one says: `git pull --rebase = git fetch + git rebase` and it does not tell why `git rebase` does not result in merge conflicts as `git rebase origin/master` does

Comment: Read the second answer.

Comment: How can it explain the things happening here? I have `o - M1` and `o-M2` and M1 and M2 are different. If you know the answer, could you please write a formal answer to elaborate why putting `M2` onto `M1` should not result in conflicts?

Comment: OP, you need to visually see what's going on in a rebase and that will clear up 99% of your questions. Try playing with this here and that should help immensely: https://onlywei.github.io/explain-git-with-d3/#rebase

Comment: @BKSpurgeon, I cannot do clone there. Neither does modify files and `commit --amend`

Comment: To me, this behavior makes perfect sense. You haven't made any changes in C2, so there are no commits in C2 that require rewriting, and it should just fast-forward. M1 isn't a new change in C2, because C1 also had M1 before you started to make changes in C1.

Answer (score 0):

git merge attempts to look at the differences between points M1 and C1 and the differences between points M1 and C2, and merge them together.

git rebase puts you at point M2, then applies each of the changes from point M1 to point C2 that was not also on the path to point M2 in sequence.  Taking this approach, it's able to get a much better understanding of what is pertinent and what isn't, so many things that seem like conflicts in the merge approach are much more obvious to work out.

---

While a lot of developers seem to like to do as few commits as possible, git rebase actually works best when each of the commits involved was small.  It all seemed like magic to me, until I tried to basically do the same thing by hand on a CVS repository.  Coworker A's change, which was just a single commit, was no easier to apply with the rebase concept, because it was all one thing.  But switching to his update, and applying Coworker B's dozens of tiny commits to it worked very well to show exactly what was intended for each update.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, could you please change your `ABC` to the letters used in the OP? According to `git help rebase`, in `C2`, it will save the commit `M1` to somewhere, and reset head to `M2`; then apply the changes saved (`M1`). Obviously, this will result in conflicts.

Comment: tried using `git checkout origin/master && git cherry-pick M1`.

Comment: I will make an attempt, but I'm uncertain I will get it right, because you seem to have a few terms wrong, and I can see a number of different ways you could be thinking them.