git rebasing for linear history
I have an issue with being unable to create a "linear" history for my branch using rebase.
I may have a wrong concept as to what can/should be done, but this is what am working with:
---A---B---E   master
       |
       |---C---D  feature

At this point both branches (master and feature) are synced with their remote counterparts, meaning that both the local and remote repositories have these commits. At this point I ran:
git checkout feature
git pull --rebase origin master

at this point, since rebase is local not remote, before I can git push i have to git pull (and i think herein lies the main issue).
So a git pull and git push later and what I expected was the following:
---A---B---E---C'---D'---MergeCommit---

But instead I end up with:
---A---B--------------------C---D---MergeCommit---
       |                            |
       |---E---C'---D'--------------|


Note: I am not sure if the C and C' are correctly placed, as i have no way of telling which of these two was the original and which is a "copy" but there are two of them present.

You can see the picture below to make it more clear.

Now, I do not mind having two "lines" here, for the lack of a better word.
I do not mind having a "merge commit". All of this is fine.
What drives me crazy is the duplicating of commit C and commit D.
Or even the following would be still be acceptable:
---A---B-------------------MergeCommit---
       |                   |
       |---E---C'---D'-----|

How do I get rid of them, on either of the "lines". I keep saying lines because all of this is a single branch. I've not dabbled with version control for a few years now, i am pretty sure this was not the behavior back when I did, and i didnt have duplicated commits, instead they were a single linear graph. I would blame git pull because of the message that i get now, which i do not recognize, Merge made by the 'ort' strategy. this seems new to me and i feel like it is the reason for the issues.

There was a similar question yesterday regarding git pull --rebase with an excellent answer by @Bert F. I suggest you to give it a look to better understand how the command actually works. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78802778/why-is-git-pull-rebase-overriding-local-commits-when-push-and-pull-are-targe Unfortunately, although git pull --merge corresponds to git fetch + git merge, git pull --rebase is not equal to git fetch + git rebase.

Forget about git pull (you were mislead by a zillion of bad tutorials) and try to recalibrate your understanding of Git without usinggit pull. It makes more harm than good. I used Git for 13 years without running git pull, not even once. Rebasing changes the branch history. If it has been pushed, git push refuses to work. You have to use git push --force or, even better, git push --force-with-lease. Read the documentation of git push: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

If you are fine with the parallel lines, why aim for a linear history? There is no virtue in having a linear history.

@dani-vta The referenced post and answer do not apply to this case.

@j6t yeah sorry, I should have expanded my comment more. I shared that link only because I saw some confusion on how OP thought that git pull --rebase works. It wasn't meant as a solution but just as a side clarification. @Axiac in fact made a very good point about not having used git push --force among some of the wrong/missing things done by OP.

I agree with OPs assessment that the issue was the regular 'git pull' of the remote feature branch after the 'git pull --rebase origin main'.  Once the rebase happened (from the git pull --rebase), the remote branch was no longer valid and should have been forced pushed over rather than pulled. Pulling with merge after pulling with rebase is what created the duplicate commits.

So reading all of this I gather that it is "okay" to force push after a rebase? Did I get this correct? For me, "force pushing" has been always presented as a BIG NO NO.
How does one resolve the collaborative work then, everyone else does not have the forced changes on their local branches?

Does anyone have an answer as to how to get a single line linear in this case?

Hi there, the unexpected commit history in your screenshot was from the master branch or the feature branch? I was confused since I could run git checkout feature -> git pull --rebase origin master and was then ABLE to run git push to push the commits to my feature branch. The commit history on my feature branch would be like A-B-E-C'-D'. You seemed to push the commits with a merge commit to master. Was there any step missing to reproduce the issue?

Would you try and run git log feature --oneline and git log origin/master --oneline to double check the commit history and compare the commit id on each local branch before push?

I have since deleted that repo so I cannot verify for sure, but the naming of the very last commit there says "Merge branch "feat....." so I would assume this tree comes from the "master branch"

I will try to recreate it once again and do as you asked

You may use those git log commands to keep records of each git commands that may change the commit history and commit id. It would be helpful for us to understand how it was reproduced.

Okay so my initial assumption that this picture was from the master branch was incorrect, it was in fact on the feature branch.
I've reproduced this issue multiple times now, and without fault it always creates this kind of graph. I have a list of steps to reproduce but it is not fitting for the "comment", if you want it, i can edit the question.
The git log --oneline indicates that the ordering is as follows: A--B--C--D--E--C'--D' after the git pull and git push

This seems insane... the git pull completely ruins / defeats the purpose of the git rebase that I want to push/keep. The commits C' and D' would essentially be "empty" because changes were already implemented by C and D...  pulling from a feature remote (in order to push back to it - as it is required by git) after rebase is as if I only did a regular merge from master, defeatus the whole purpose of rebase

There is no way to rebase a feature branch (i.e. have a linear history) without a force push of some kind later (well, I guess you could delete the remote branch and recreate from the new local). A non-force push requires that the local branch has only added commits to the tip of the remote - a rebase explicitly moves the whole branch.

I think the main issue here is that OP didn't know to the full extent what rebase did, and the full consequences, related to pushing and pulling. In my opinion, if you're in this situation, rebasing, and force-pushing should be left alone, completely. These commands should come with a truckload of warnings and stopsigns, to avoid aiming a footgun either on your own feet, or the feet of your team. Accept the railroad history you will create and mitigate this by not working on umpteen tasks in parallel.

NOTE: I've only used this workflow with non-shared feature branches. OP mentions they have a different use case (see comments), so they would have to adapt this workflow or use a different one.

I've mocked up a repo similar to yours: I've got a feature branch 'feature'/eabd641 originally branched off of local 'master'/5d2cce8. After git fetch --all, we see the remote 'master' branch has advanced to new commit 82e4b59.
* eabd641 Mon Jul 29 12:01:01 2024 -0400 test 1
|  (origin/feature, feature)
| * 82e4b59 Sun May 5 23:15:23 2024 -0400 Fix bug
|/   (origin/master)
* 5d2cce8 Sun May 5 21:54:15 2024 -0400 3/3 challenges
|  (HEAD -> master)
* f0994f1 Sun May 5 18:06:48 2024 -0400 2/3 challenges

If I apply the command OP used
git checkout feature
git pull --rebase origin master

My repo now looks like this. My feature branch was rebased onto remote tracking 'origin/main'/82e4b59 (my local 'master' was not updated). The feature is now linear because it is off the tip of (remote) master, but my remote tracking branch 'origin/feature' is now out of sync due to the rebase.  The 'test 1' commit exists in local and remote feature branches - a git pull now would merge to local and remote which keep both 'test 1' commits in the history as OP saw.
* b1f6f71 Mon Jul 29 12:01:01 2024 -0400 test 1
|  (HEAD -> feature)
* 82e4b59 Sun May 5 23:15:23 2024 -0400 Fix bug
|  (origin/master, origin/main)
| * eabd641 Mon Jul 29 12:01:01 2024 -0400 test 1
|/   (origin/feature)
* 5d2cce8 Sun May 5 21:54:15 2024 -0400 3/3 challenges
|  (master)
* f0994f1 Sun May 5 18:06:48 2024 -0400 2/3 challenges

While still on my local feature branch, I would now git push -f to sync the remote 'feature' branch with the rebase, then do a build and run tests to code is good, do one more fetch to check the remote 'master' hasn't advanced again, then git checkout master, git pull and git merge feature (this will fast-forward - add --no-ff if you want a merge commit). Finally, do a git push of master (normal push, not a force push).
Not sure I like using 'git pull --rebase origin master' to combine a pull and rebase to rebase the feature onto the tip of the remote tracking 'origin/master'. I would rather be first update local 'master' and then explicitly rebase 'feature' onto my local 'master', then git push -f. You need to update the local 'master' at some point anyway.

Aside: Something I do when learning new git commands or learning a new workflow: look at the git tree before each command, predict what it will look like after, run the command, and then look at the git tree after. Any time it didn't do what you expected, did deeper into why - did I use the command wrong or use the wrong args or did I misunderstand what the command does?
Also, have a good git log alias to make visualizing the git tree easy - Pretty Git branch graphs

I do not mind updating the local master, i thought pull --rebase was just a shortcut. How to handle teammate's local machines collaboration with that have a different copy due to a push -f ? Just have them delete their copies and pull?
What if they have local commits (not yet pushed) based on the previous history, is there a way to amend?

Never force push master nor any shared branch. You can only force push a feature branch like this when you are the only dev working it - no one else should have local commits. If there are multiple devs working on the same feature branch, you should not use this workflow because you should never use force push on shared branches. The other devs' remote tracking branches will update automatically. If other devs have checked out your branch, they will should delete their local branch and check it out fresh. Test this workflow with other devs and get comfortable with it before using it regularly.

I understand but I have a NEED to rebase a shared branch... Which requires a force push for that rebase to make any sense. Reasoning is, there is a, lets say "project agnostic" and "project specific" files in the repo, and project agnostic files are a part of a different repo, which gets its own updates, which we can "rebase" to pull the updates into the specific project because  the project specific ones came from that repo (has history)

I understand that git being a "version control" is not really being used as VERSION control here as we are "rewritting history".... but it is used more like file updater/differ/manager

"I have a NEED to rebase a shared branch" - unfortunately, this is not a use case I've had experience with, so I'm not familiar with a way your team could use coordinate updates to a branch like this.

We have opted to have coordinated rebasing between sprints and if a PR is open, it gets squashed into a single commit then cherry picked instead. We will see how it goes. Thanks for all the explanations it was helpful
