After merge to master, rebase with master giving conflicts for all files merged to master
Case
A new branch created for given requirement

Adding changes as per requirement in the branch and

Below commands executed every time we commit

git add .
git commit -m "comment" (committing changes to branch)
git pull --rebase origin master (rebase branch with master)
git fetch
git push -f origin <branch_name>




Finally raised a pull request
Once approved merged either normal or squashed-way

Problem
Now here, conflicts come every time:

After merge to master, when again on same branch running

git pull --rebase origin master (rebase branch with master)


Then it’s showing conflicts in all the files where changes were done and
It’s not getting resolved in one go and
Need to make the changes again and again in the files for the count of commits and
Then only rebase is getting successful



How to resolve this
Please advice how to avoid this and any change required in approach?

git pull --rebase origin master is not the same as git fetch origin master + git rebase origin/master. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78802778/why-is-git-pull-rebase-overriding-local-commits-when-push-and-pull-are-targe for further explanation

Also, why would you push force after rebasing your local changes on top of the remote's? Like so, if any further change had been pushed to the remote while you were rebasing, you would overwrite them with your history.

@dani-vta: it looks like the OP is working on a feature branch, and regularly rebases this branch on top of origin/master, which isn't the remote tracking branch.

OP: there is quite a strong difference between "regular merge" and "squash". In your case which is it ? It is expected to have conflicts if you rebase on top of a squash merge. After the merge request has been completed and squash-merged, you should run git rebase --onto master <integrated_commit> <my_branch> to instruct git to not replay the commits up to integrated_commit.

It's not clear what branch you are rebasing after the PR is completed. Is it another feature branch you were working on or the same branch that you just created the PR with?

@TTT ... same branch

git pull --rebase origin master is not pulling and rebasing master to your branch.
You should

git checkout master
git pull --rebase
git checkout -
git rebase master


Its also not solving the issue .... and again the branch into rebasing for all items we pushed in earlier pull request.
