git pull --rebase failed

This shows git status nothing to commit, working tree clean
Left line show the git line
I use webstorm to update my project. click Update Project button these commands are run:
14:42:17.357: [app] git -c credential.helper= -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false fetch origin --recurse-submodules=no --progress --prune

14:42:20.580: [app] git -c credential.helper= -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false -c core.commentChar= rebase origin/dev_core

It show me err messages:
Rebasing (1/10)
Rebasing (2/10)
Rebasing (3/10)
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    src/main/tpscalc.node
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
hint: Could not execute the todo command
hint:
hint:     pick 4162fea9e489405ac30633020ca1fe11ca22f6b3 feat: worker 引入 addon 并运行用例
hint:
hint: It has been rescheduled; To edit the command before continuing, please
hint: edit the todo list first:
hint:
hint:     git rebase --edit-todo
hint:     git rebase --continue

I have run git rebase --edit-todo and git rebase --continue and git rebase --skip all of these commands are not working for me.
The command line git pull --rebase show me:

I'm pretty sure that remote commit didn't modify .node file.
Here is remote commit details:

So, how can i rebase? Now i can merge but the line is not clean which is not what i want.
Update:
I droped remote commit and force push to origin now I can execute git pull --rebase successfully.
But I really do not know why that commit make me rebase failed. Only package.json and package-lock.json have conflicts. In the past the websorm show me a dialog to merge. but this time just failed

In your title you've written git pull --rebase while the commands being executed are git [...] fetch origin --recurse-submodules=no --progress --prune followed by git [...] rebase origin/dev_core. git pull --rebase is not equivalent to git fetch origin branch followed by git rebase origin/branch. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78802778/why-is-git-pull-rebase-overriding-local-commits-when-push-and-pull-are-targe for more. Can you clarify what commands have been exactly executed?

@dani-vta My fault, Both git pull --rebase and git [...] fetch origin --recurse-submodules=no --progress --prune  git [...] rebase origin/dev_core. git pull --rebase are executed.  same result

@dani-vta Added to the details of the question the git pull --rebase screenshot. Thanks

Cleaning indexes has helped me.
Remove every file from Git's index
git rm --cached -r .

Rewrite the Git index to pick up all the new line endings
git reset --hard

Hope it helps

Maybe we have different problems. It not work for me.
