How does git rebase handle amended commits without conflicting
Consider the following example:

I change a file and change content X to A and push this change
Somebody else pulls and changes A to B
They amend or squash these changes and force push, so now on origin there is a commit that just does X->B, and I still have X->A locally
I do git pull --rebase
Git somehow resolves this automatically so I now have X->B as well, and A has completely disappeared

I have looked for explanations but all the information I can find says that git doesn't track any additional information about rebases so this situation should be exactly the same as if X->B was created from X instead of amending X->A. But this doesn't make sense:

git merge produces a merge conflict
If X->B was created from X instead of amending X->A then that also results in a conflict, even when rebasing

So what is it that allows git to rebase amended commits automatically without conflict?

Good question! I was wondering the same recently

There is a brilliant answer by @BertF that explains quite in depth how git pull --rebase works and that could help you with your example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78802778/why-is-git-pull-rebase-overriding-local-commits-when-push-and-pull-are-targe

When you do not say what your want to pull as in
git pull --rebase

then some wizardry kicks in.
First, it pulls from the upstream that is configured for the current branch.
Second, it uses the --forkpoint machinery of git rebase, which looks into the reflog to know what you have already pushed to the upstream and which commits are still only local.

I think the answer is that git does not "complain" in the form of a conflict if the same change is coming from the two sides of a merge (rebasign/cherry-picking is a special case of merge). So in this case git notices that the same change is coming from both sides and it skips it.
Just in case, the fact that there was an amend does not matter to git.

Yes but in this case it's not the same change - if I merge it is a conflict (between A and B), but rebase somehow also seems to know that somebody intentionally changed A to B, even though the commits are X->A and X->B independently.

What matters is the differences between the common ancestor and the two tips.... In a rebase, well, it's like a cherry-pick so the forced ancestor is the parent of the commit being cherry-picked. Can you compare the 3 involved commits dor that cherry-pick and confirm if a conflict should or shouldn't be there?
